# Using ifstream, ofstream and fstream

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

1. Trying to read into a file the word, "beef"
2. Later going and editing the contents of the file to whatever to user wants which will be stored in the string, "line"
3. The file never displays and when I go to check it manually, the text file is blank.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string line = { " " };
    ofstream file1;
    file1.open("beef.txt");
    file1 << "beef" << endl;
    file1.close();
    file1.open("beef.txt");

    if (file1.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Enter what you would like to be contained in the file" << endl;
        cin >> line;
        ofstream file1;
        file1 << line << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ofstream file1;` don't do that.

Comment: You need a good round of [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: @SombreroChicken You should probably mention which one of them

Comment: You can easily debug this code with step-by-step debugging. Just use your debugger, go line by line and see what is on your disk after each statement. I believe that helps you more than if we simply wrote here what is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In this snippet:

```
if (file1.is_open())
{
    cout << "Enter what you would like to be contained in the file" << endl;
    cin >> line;
    ofstream file1;
    file1 << line << endl;
}
```

You create another `ofstream` object:

```
ofstream file1;
```

This shadows the one you had already created before. Moreover, the one you are shadowing now is the object that contains a valid file pointer to `"beef.txt"`. Using the new inner-scope `file1` doesn't point to any file yet, thus writing to it won't give you any results in `"beef.txt"`.

Remove it to use the correct object:

```
if (file1.is_open())
{
    cout << "Enter what you would like to be contained in the file" << endl;
    cin >> line;
    file1 << line << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the string is being saved to the file now, but the output is the issue. I'm using ifstream to display the file, but it is still blank. (forgive my noviceness)

Comment: @EthanOnweller: please edit your question to show how you are trying to use `ifstream`. Either it is not able to open the file and you are not checking for that, or you are not reading from it correctly.

Answer (score 2):

A `std::ofstream` is for output only, you can't read input with it.

A `std::ifstream` is for input only, you can't write output with it.

So, you need to either

- use separate `std::ofstream` and `std::ifstream` variables:

  ```
  int main()
  {
      ofstream out_file;
      ifstream in_file;
      string line;

      out_file.open("beef.txt", ios_base::trunc);
      if (out_file.is_open())
      {
          out_file << "beef" << endl;
          out_file.close();
      }

      in_file.open("beef.txt");
      if (in_file.is_open())
      {
          getline(in_file, line);
          in_file.close();

          cout << "File contains:" << endl;
          cout << line << endl;
      }

      cout << "Enter what you would like to be contained in the file" << endl;
      getline(cin, line);

      out_file.open("beef.txt", ios_base::trunc);
      if (out_file.is_open())
      {
          out_file << line << endl;
          out_file.close();
      } 

      in_file.open("beef.txt");
      if (in_file.is_open())
      {
          getline(in_file, line);
          in_file.close();

          cout << "File now contains:" << endl;
          cout << line << endl;
      }

      return 0;
  }
  ```
- use a single `std::fstream` variable, which can be used for both output and input, depending on whether you specify `in` and/or `out` flags when calling `open()`:

  ```
  int main()
  {
      fstream file;
      string line;

      file.open("beef.txt", ios_base::out | ios_base::trunc);
      if (file.is_open())
      {
          file << "beef" << endl;
          file.close();
      }

      file.open("beef.txt", ios_base::in);
      if (file.is_open())
      {
          getline(file, line);
          file.close();

          cout << "File contains:" << endl;
          cout << line << endl;
      }

      cout << "Enter what you would like to be contained in the file" << endl;
      getline(cin, line);

      file.open("beef.txt", ios_base::out | ios_base::trunc);
      if (file.is_open())
      {
          file << line << endl;
          file.close();
      }

      file.open("beef.txt", ios_base::in);
      if (in_file.is_open())
      {
          getline(in_file, line);
          in_file.close();

          cout << "File now contains:" << endl;
          cout << line << endl;
      }

      return 0;
  }
  ```

Comment: I think he doesn't want to read files at all. Just uses wrong English to express writing by saying "read into a file".

Comment: @AlKepp: the question is also tagged with `[ifstream]`, and the OP has mentioned in comments that he is also trying to use `ifstream` to display the file, so I included use of `ifstream` in my answer