# What is the difference between ifstream, ofstream and fstream?

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

In C++ file handling, I came across `ifstream`, `ofstream` and `fstream`. Can anyone tell me the main difference between these?

Comment: [`ifstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream), [`ofstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream), [`fstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream).

Comment: Dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49563597/using-ifstream-ofstream-and-fstream

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is how the class hierarchy looks like:
[image]
<sub>From https://www.cplusplus.com/img/iostream.gif</sub>

The three classes that deal with file handling are:

- `basic_ifstream`
- `basic_ofstream`
- `basic_fstream`

`ifstream`, `ofstream` and `fstream` are "`char`" [template specializations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) which means they are nothing but `basic_ifstream<char>`, `basic_ofstream<char>` and `basic_fstream<char>` i.e. they deal with reading and writing `char`s from a file.

- `ifstream` is input file stream which allows you to read the contents of a file.
- `ofstream` is output file stream which allows you to write contents to a file.
- `fstream` allows both reading from and writing to files by default. However, you can have an `fstream` behave like an `ifstream` or `ofstream` by passing in the `ios::open_mode` flag.

### `ios::openmode` Flags

---

The open mode flags are:

| Flag | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `ios::app` | All write operations must occur at the end of the file |
| `ios::binary` | Open in binary mode |
| `ios::in` | Open for reading |
| `ios::out` | Open for writing |
| `ios::trunc` | Empty the contents of the file after opening |
| `ios::ate` | Go to the end of the file after opening |

These flags are additive which means you can combine multiple flags using the bitwise OR `|` operator. If I want to open the file in binary mode and append, I can combine the flags as follows:

```
ios::binary | ios::app
```

- `ifstream` always has the `ios::in` flag set and it cannot be removed. Similary, `ofstream` always has the `ios::out` flag set and it cannot be removed. Any other flags added will be combined with `ios::in` for `ifstream` and `ios::out` for `ofstream`
- On the other hand, if you do not pass any flags to `fstream`, the default is `ios::in | ios::out`, so you can read from as well as write to the file. But if you specify a flag explicitly for `fstream` like `ios::in`, it will be opened only for reading, like an `ifstream`.

#### How to pass flags?

You can do so in the constructor or when calling `open()`:

```
ifstream infile("filepath", ios::binary); //Open the file for reading in binary mode, ios::in will always be set
ofstream outfile("filepath", ios::trunc); // Open the file for writing and clear its contents, ios::out is implicitly set
fstream inoutfile("filepath") // default flag will be: ios::in | ios::out hence both reads and writes possible
fstream infile("filepath", ios::in) // file will be opened in read mode like fstream
```

It is basically possible to never use `ifstream` and `ofstream` and always use `fstream` with the required flags. But it is prone to accidental errors while setting the flags. Hence, using `ifstream` you can be sure that writes will never occur and with `ofstream` only writes will take place.

#### Edit (`ios::noreplace`)

C++ 23 adds the `ios::noreplace` flag which opens a file exclusively for writing. This flag already existed in some implementations but is now [standardized](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2467r1.html) in C++ 23. If the file already exists, it fails to open.

Comment: The last sentence should be amended to something like:
Hence, using ifstream you can be sure that reads will always be enabled independent from using (or not using) any masks. By analogy, writes will always be enabled for ofstream.

Answer (score 5):

`ifstream` is for input only.

`ofstream` is for output only.

`fstream` can be used for both/either input and/or output.

Answer (score 4):

Key is in the names:

- `ifstream` = "input file stream" which is a type of `istream` or "input stream"
- `ofstream` = "output file stream" which is a type of `ostream` or "output stream"
- `fstream` = "(bidirectional) file stream" as in `iostream` ("input/output stream") as in [includes both aspects](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) through inheritance